# How can I ignore a Specific Index? Python

Tags: python, list, loops

I am trying to parse a JSON output and if a Index has the userId of 5, I want to ignore it. The problem is that it still does not ignore it.

Here is how i read the json (works):

```
import json
import urllib.request

url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts"
data = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read().decode()

site_info =json.loads(data)

for info in site_info:
  print(f"{}, {}, {}, {}".format(info["userId"], info["id"],
                                 info["title"], info["body"]))
```

Here is how I prepare a list of userIds to inspect (removal of 5 does not work):

```
mylist= [{"userId":1}, {"userId":2}, {"userId":3}, {"userId":4}, {"userId":5}, 
         {"userId":6}, {"userId":7}, {"userId":8}, {"userId":9}, {"userId":10}]

for i in range(len(mylist)-5, -5, -5):
    print(i)
    if mylist[i]["userId"] == 5:
        mylist.pop(i)

print (mylist)
```

I also need to use `.pop` as part of the assignment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code does exactly what you told it to:

- it checks the positions 5 and 0 on your `mylist` n
- if either had a `mylist[i]["userId"] == 5` something would be done
- neither has `mylist[i]["userId"] == 5` so it does nothing.

Beside that: [NEVER change a list while iterating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260089/strange-result-when-removing-item-from-a-list-while-iterating-over-it) (unless you know how-to - you do not do it correctly).

You can remember indexes to pop and pop them seperately:

```
idx_to_delete = []

for idx,value in enumerate(mylist):
    if value["userId"] == 5:
        idx_to_delete.append(idx)

# reverse - because if you pop 2 and then 5 the popping of 2
# would lead to 5 now being 4 etc. if you pop the higher ones 
# first you do not have that problem.
# reversed(idx_to_delete) == idx_to_delete[::-1]
for id in reversed(idx_to_delete):
    mylist.pop(id)
```

---

To raise the quality of your question, you should

1. remove all the JSON stuff - you never use site_info for your *actual* problem so it does not belong into a minimal reproducible example
2. get rid of things that confuse you: `range(len(mylist)-5, -5, -5)` evaluates to `range(10-5, -5, -5)` and results in `5,0` if iterated - so replace it with `for i in (5,0):`. If you check `mylist[5]` and `mylist[0]` you'll see that NEITHER has a `["userId"] == 5`.

Your questions code would boil down to

> ```
> mylist= [{"userId":1},{"userId":2},{"userId":3},{"userId":4},{"userId":5}, 
>          {"userId":6},{"userId":7},{"userId":8},{"userId":9},{"userId":10}]
>
> for i in (5,0):
>     print(i)
>     if mylist[i]["userId"] == 5:
>         mylist.pop(i)
>
> print (mylist)
> ```
>
> Why does the "userId" == 5 not get popped? List is unchanged?

If would probably be easier if you did

```
id_to_ignore = {5,}

mylist = [{"userId":id} for id in range(10) if id not in id_to_ignore]

# or as loop
# mylist = []
# for id in range(1,11):
#    if id in id_to_ignore: 
#        continue
#    mylist.append( {"userId":id})
```